# Odd JAVA compile error?

Tags: java

I need to preface this with I am not allowed to use an IDE in class, I must use TextPad to compile and run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

There are three files, a driver file and two other class files. The Lab4 file is the driver file and the class files are "ITEM" and "NAME".

**I am getting the following errors when I compile the driver "Lab4" file.**

```
     F:\Java\Lab 4A\Lab4.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println ("Manufacturer's Name: " + item.manName());
                                                      ^
      symbol:   method manName()
      location: variable item of type Item
```

The code for the **"Lab4"** file is here:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Lab4
    {
     public static void main (String[] args)
    {
          String firstName = "";
          String lastName = "";
          String manName = "";
          float cost = 0.00f;
          int itemNum = 0;


        // Instantiate class files
        // Variables are declared because variables are expected in name.java file
        Name name = new Name("Bob", "Jones");
        Item item = new Item(985534, 9.99f, "Lewis Mfg");


        // Create a scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        // Recieve user input for variables
        System.out.println ("Please enter the customer's first name: ");
        firstName = input.next();
        while (firstName.length() < 1)
            {
            System.out.println ("Enter a valid first name");
            firstName = input.next();
            }
            name.setfirstName(firstName);
            firstName = "";

        System.out.println ("Please enter the customer's last name: ");
        lastName = input.next();
        while (lastName.length() < 1)
            {
            System.out.println ("Enter a valid last name: ");
            lastName = input.next();
            }
            name.setlastName(lastName);
            lastName = "";

        System.out.println ("Please enter the item number: ");
        itemNum = input.nextInt();
        while (itemNum < 1)
            {
            System.out.println ("Enter a valid item number: ");
            itemNum = input.nextInt();
            }
            item.setitemNum(itemNum);
            itemNum = 0;

        System.out.println ("Please enter the item's cost (including decimal): ");
        cost = input.nextFloat();
        while (cost < 1)
            {
            System.out.println ("Enter a valid cost amount: ");
            cost = input.nextFloat();
            }
        item.setcost(cost);
            cost = 0;

        System.out.println ("Please enter the manufacturer's name: ");
        manName = input.next();
        while (manName.length() < 1)
            {
            System.out.println ("Enter a valid manufacturer's name");
            manName = input.next();
            }
            item.setmanName(manName);
            manName = "";


        // Outputs the data entered by the user and stored in the other classes,               Name and Item
           System.out.println ("First Name: " + name.getfirstName() + "\n");
           System.out.println ("Last Name: " + name.getlastName() + "\n");
           System.out.println ("Item Number: " + item.getitemNum() + "\n");
       System.out.println ("Item Cost: " + item.getcost() + "\n");
       System.out.println ("Manufacturer's Name: " + item.manName());

        System.out.println ("\n\nThe customer and item information have been          entered.\n");

     }
     }
```

The code for the **"ITEM"** file that is referenced in the error is here:

```
     public class Item
{
    // Create private variables that cannot be accessed directly
     private int itemNum;
     private float cost;
     private String manName;

     // Create instances of the private variables that can be set by the methods
     public Item (int itemNum, float cost, String manName)
            {
            this.itemNum = itemNum;
            this.cost = cost;
        this.manName = manName;
        }

    // Gets the variable values from the user via the driver class
    public int getitemNum()
        {
        return itemNum;
        }

    public float getcost()
        {
        return cost;
        }

    public String getmanName()
        {
        return manName;
        }


    // Sets the variable amounts into the private variables after validating the input     form
    public boolean setitemNum(int itemNum)
        {
        if (itemNum < 0)
        return false;
        else
        this.itemNum = itemNum;
        return true;
        }

    public boolean setcost(float cost)
        {
        if (cost < 0)
        return false;
        else
        this.cost = cost;
        return true;
        }

    public boolean setmanName(String manName)
        {
        if (manName.length() < 0)
        return false;
        else
            this.manName = manName;
        return true;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You probably wanted `item.getmanName()`, instead of `item.manName()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You named your method `getmanName()`, but called `manName()` on the error line.

Answer (score 2):

You got simple typo error:

You want `item.getmanName()` and not `manName()`

Answer (score 2):

`manName` is an attribute, you are referencing it as a method `manName()`

since `manName` is `private` you have to use the accessor you have called `getmanName()`

the proper reference given your code would be `item.getmanName()`

a better idiomatic name for the method would be `getManName()` following proper `UpperCamelCase` naming conventions for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking manName() but your method is getmanName()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no `manName` method in the `Item` class. Getter method is called `getmanName`. Generally there is that rule telling that getter method should start with the **get** word and after that You should place the class attribute name that You want to get value of.

Change line that gives compilation error to:

```
System.out.println ("Manufacturer's Name: " + item.getmanName());
```

Now it should work.